# message:Repo 'maven' was not found

Tags: android, bintray

I get this `message:Repo 'maven' was not found` when uploading your android library to Bintray, what should do?
I am following this tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/52-building-an-android-library-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [step 4](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin#step-4-add-your-bintray-package-information-to-the-bintray-closure) in the [gradle-bintray-plugin](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin) readme states:

> repo - existing repository in bintray to add the artifacts to (for example: 'generic', 'maven' etc)

In the blog you have attached it also states, in the `Setup your Bintray Account` step, that you need to `Add New Repository`. You can create a new repository by using the UI or using [Bintray's API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Bintray+REST+API#BintrayRESTAPI-CreateRepository) to create repository.

You can save yourself a lot of problems by following the guide.

Answer (score 0):

as in thos post answered https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/143

> I created manually repository with name 'maven' in my bintray account and it solved my problem

you should just do manualy